# Python-GnuPG encryption returns blank(Key exist in home directory)

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

For sending secure mail i have using [Python-GnuPG](http://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#getting-started) for encrypting the mail. So i started to follow the documentation and a tutorial on this [link](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/) . I have created the key in home directory and started to testing for encrypting a string. While encrypting the string it returns blank and i have print the result of status of encrypted string it also returns blank. What will be the possible issue? Here's what i am tried already:

```
>>> import gnupg
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/saravanan/.gnupg')
>>> unencrypted_string = 'Who are you? How did you get in my house?'
>>> encrypted_data = gpg.encrypt(unencrypted_string, 'test@mail.com')
>>> encrypted_string = str(encrypted_data)
>>> print encrypted_string

>>> print encrypted_data.status
```

From above both

> encrypted_string

and

> encrypted_data.status

returns blank.

Comment: Use `encrypted_string` and `encrypted_data.status` instead of `print ...`, to see the actual `repr` of the values

Comment: When use `encrypted_data.status` without  `print` it retruns `' '`